# How manage validity range date in Ms Access database

Tags: database, ms-access

I need your help for a query in MS Access.

I have two table:

- one called Tblvalrules with Department code, date of validity of rules and rule to apply for that starting date. That’s mean that on Dep01 from 1/1/2018 is to apply the rule1 and always on Dep01 from 1/1/2020 will be to apply rule2.
- another table called TblMovement with dates and dep.

I would like a query that add a column **Ruletoapply** that on the basis of dep and date of TblMovement search on Tblvalrules and add the correct rule to apply

Here below the tables examples for a better understand

**Tblvalrules**

```
Dep    |  ValidityDateFrom | Rule  | 
------------------------------------
Dep001 |   1/1/2018        | rule1 | 
Dep001 |   1/1/2020        | rule2 | 
Dep002 |   1/1/2016        | rule3 | 
Dep003 |   1/1/2018        | rule4 | 
Dep003 |   1/1/2020        | rule5 |
```

**TblMovement**

```
Date       | Dep    | **Ruletoapply**
------------------------------------
02/01/2018 | Dep001 | **rule1**
02/01/2019 | Dep003 | **rule4**
06/06/2020 | Dep003 | **rule5**
```

Thank you in advance also if you have some advice for Database design

Comment: Are dates Feb 1 or Jan 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First join the tables and aggregate to find the `ValidityDateFrom` for each row of `TblMovement` and then join the result to `Tblvalrules` to get the proper `Rule`:

```
select t.Date, t.Dep, r.Rule as Ruletoapply
from (
  select m.Date, m.Dep, max(v.ValidityDateFrom) as ValidityDateFrom
  from TblMovement as m left join Tblvalrules v 
  on v.Dep = m.Dep and v.ValidityDateFrom <= m.Date 
  group by m.Date, m.Dep
) as t inner join Tblvalrules as r 
on r.ValidityDateFrom = t.ValidityDateFrom and r.Dep = t.Dep
```

Results:

```
Date        Dep     Ruletoapply
2/1/2018    Dep001  rule 1
2/1/2019    Dep003  rule 4
6/6/2020    Dep003  rule 5
```

Comment: Only one note if you could help me.
If the TblMovement contain a duplicate value for example another entry
02/01/2018 | Dep001 |
is it possible to manage it because in that case the result I will miss a line of TblMovement?

I'd like to have all details in TblMovement without have a group query.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean Tblvalrules?

Comment: In TblMovement I could have duplicated dates and duplicated Dep

Comment: You will need another join which would make the query slower: `select m.Date, m.Dep, t.Ruletoapply
from TblMovement as m
left join (
  select t.Date, t.Dep, r.Rule as Ruletoapply
 from (
    select m.Date, m.Dep, max(v.ValidityDateFrom) as ValidityDateFrom
    from TblMovement as m left join Tblvalrules v 
    on v.Dep = m.Dep and v.ValidityDateFrom <= m.Date 
    group by m.Date, m.Dep
  ) as t inner join Tblvalrules as r 
  on r.ValidityDateFrom = t.ValidityDateFrom and r.Dep = t.Dep
) as t on t.Date = m.Date and t.Dep = m.Dep`